# Simple Ember.js `has-many` relationship not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm running into an issue of querying data against Ember data.

I have three models:

`media`: which multiple models inherit from
`image`: which inherits from `media`
`note`: which is a standard model.

I'm trying to get all of the `note`s of an `image` but the query I'm trying isn't working.

---

```
// imageModel.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';
import MediaModel from 'models/mediaModel';

export default MediaModel.extend({ 
    fileName: DS.attr('string'),
    fileExt: DS.attr('string'),

    url: DS.attr('string'),
});


// mediaModel.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    notes: DS.hasMany('note', { inverse: 'noteable' }),
});


// noteModel.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    category: DS.attr('string'),
    text: DS.attr('string'),

    image: DS.belongsTo('image'),
    noteable: DS.belongsTo('media-model', { polymorphic: true }),
});
```

Once I have an `image`, I do `image.get('notes.length')`, but even if an image does have `note`s associated with it, I'm always getting back `0`. Am I querying this the wrong way?

Does the fact that `image` belongs to `media` affect how I can query the `hasMany` of `media`?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not certain you can inherit in that way with an ember-data model. We're using mixins right now to share common attributes and computed properties and waiting for ES Classes to land to try a path like this instead.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @jrjohnson. What would prohibit this kind of setup from working? Shouldn't the property being on the parent model just act like it's on the child one?

Comment: I have no idea, just a wild guess. Since it's javascript extending an EmberObject (or any JS object) involves dealing with prototypal inheritance. It's possible that EmberData isn't reading the properties in the base object since they are not properties on the final object. Or it may be none of these things. I just haven't ever seen this type of extension done with a ember-data model and want to let you know that it may very well just not work and mixins (while not considered a great solution) may be your best best at this point in time. Or it might work and I'm completely wrong :)

Comment: You shouldn't add a `Model` suffix to your filenames. That goes against Ember CLI naming convetions and could lead to very strange behavior. If `model` is part of your model name (which sounds strange but maybe the case) the name should still be dasherized (`note-model.js` instead of `noteModel.js`).

Comment: Every solved so question should have an accepted answer. Please accept the answer which helped you best.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a bug. Your hasMany-definition in mediaModel.js has an invalid model-name.

Change

```
notes: DS.hasMany('note', { inverse: 'noteable' }),
```

to

```
notes: DS.hasMany('note-model', { inverse: 'noteable' }),
```

Here's a working [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/6454331922fc6b35fdc9f64123260665?openFiles=models.note-model.js%2C) of the fixed code. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason, nothing changes when I do that.

Comment: Please post the code, which fetches the image with its notes loaded and show the payload.

Comment: @qarthandso I found the issue. Check out my answer.